# Bookmarking the rotation, scale, and extent in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have one map that I want to bookmark at multiple
rotations/orientations.

However, when I use the **bookmark tool** to capture the view, I am only able to capture the scale and extent of each view, and not the rotation.

For example, I saved this view as a bookmark, labelled 'Horizontal" (note the rotation at -29.0):
[image]

When I change the rotation to 60 degrees to get the following view:
[image]

And I use aforementioned 'Horizontal' bookmark to get back to the original view, the scale and extent of map changes, but the rotation remains at 60, instead of changing to -29:
[image]

I have tested this on QGIS versions 3.0, 2.99, and 2.18.16 on Windows computer.

Is there a better way to create multiple default layouts that include map extent, scale, and rotation?

Comment: Looking at an exported bookmark xml it does not appear to have a rotation element, so perhaps it is not supported. Print composer supports different rotations for different print layouts or even different maps within the same layout. Could that fit your needs?

Comment: Rotation is not stored in bookmarks, but it's a good idea. I'd post it as a feature request on issues.qgis.org